# Using 'Batch Rename' and 'Photoshop Actions' to put a prefix on 'Save as' files

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'll try to make this as clear as possible. I'll add mock filenames to try and make it easier to follow. The images I'm working with are for design prints that I sell locally.

I am currently exporting a file from Coreldraw as a 4-Layered PSD. In this instance we'll call it: `Baker.PSD`

I then open `Baker.PSD` in Photoshop CS6

I then run an action which opens a template file `Template.PSD`

This contains four Smart Objects. The script duplicates each of the layers from `Baker.PSD` into its own Smart Object in the template file.

The script then saves the file as `xx-FINAL.PSD`
Then it goes on to save the file as

```
xx-GREY.JPG
and
xx-GREY.TIF
```

It then changes the grey background colour to blue and saves as

```
xx-BLUE.JPG
and
xx-BLUE.TIF
```

.. it continues to do this for another five colours.

I end up with a directory with the following files:

```
xx-FINAL.PSD
xx-GREY.JPG
xx-GREY.TIF
xx-BLUE.JPG
xx-BLUE.TIF
xx-BROWN.JPG
xx-BROWN.TIF
etc.
```

I then have to go to the directory in Explorer and either use a 3rd party tool, or manually rename all the files until I have the following:

```
Baker-FINAL.PSD
Baker-GREY.JPG
Baker-GREY.TIF
Baker-BLUE.JPG
Baker-BLUE.TIF
Baker-BROWN.JPG
Baker-BROWN.TIF
etc.
```

I've been trying to understand if this is possible to do within Photoshop, and have seen similar posts that use Batch Rename whilst ticking the 'Overide Save As' option to achieve similar tasks, but none so far where multiple Save As are used from one action.

Thanks in advance, and any help is appreciated!

Comment: how comfortable are you with javascript/vbscript/applescript? What OS?

Comment: I'm on Win8.1 and would class myself as well below average on vbscript... with zero knowledge on the rest.

Comment: Just use Powershell which is the modern incarnation of DOS-Prompt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874915/rename-multiple-files-in-a-folder-add-a-prefix-windows

Answer (score 1):

To start, it looks as if both Photoshop and Bridge function in a similar when batching files. Although **neither one**, from what I can see, **can replace a prefix, you can add an additional one**.

So going by your example, If I added the prefix "Baker-" they would appear as:

**(Baker-"Current File name".extension)**

Baker-xx-FINAL.PSD

Baker-xx-GREY.JPG

Baker-xx-GREY.TIF

etc.

To do this, in PS CC you can File > Automate > Batch

- Select Source folder
- Check any necessary boxes for Dialogue pop ups
- Determine how errors are handled
- Choose a destination folder (where you want them to save)
- Next Determine your File naming convention

  - In the first slot select NONE and customize your prefix **(Baker-)**
  - In the second slot select DOCUMENT NAME **(xx-FINAL)**
  - In the third slot select EXTENSION **(.PSD)**

(You can add additional naming conventions)

**Click OK**

(Bridge works in a similar way. Highlight the files you want to rename. Right-CLick > Batch Rename)

Hopefully these alternatives work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For batch renaming and simple image operations I often use a free image viewer tool - [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

- Open IrfanView;
- click on File > Batch Conversion / Rename;
- choose "Batch rename" mode;
- in the "Batch rename settings" section you can set a name pattern with options for find/replace strings in the file names.